# .vbs script that echo's the Bitlocker status of the C Drive

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to create a .vbs script that will echo the BitLocker status of a computers C drive.

I tried using the following code but I got the error 0X80041003, Source: (null).

```
strComputer = "." 
Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell") 
strEnvSysDrive = objShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%SystemDrive%") 

Set objWMIServiceBit = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\CIMV2\Security\MicrosoftVolumeEncryption") 
Set colItems = objWMIServiceBit.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_EncryptableVolume",,48) 

For Each objItem in colItems 
    If objItem.DriveLetter = strEnvSysDrive Then 
        strDeviceC = objItem.DeviceID 
        DriveC =  "Win32_EncryptableVolume.DeviceID='"&strDeviceC&"'" 
        Set objOutParams = objWMIServiceBit.ExecMethod(DriveC, "GetProtectionStatus") 
        If objOutParams.ProtectionStatus = "1" Then 
            wscript.Echo "Bitlocker is enabled" 
        Else 
            wscript.Echo "Bitlocker is disabled" 
        End if 
    End If 
Next
```

Does anyone know why I keep getting this error or have any .vbs script that will echo the BitLocker status of the C Drive?

Comment: On which line do you get the error?

Comment: I get it on  Line: 5 Char: 1

Comment: Quick Google search for the error code in relation to WMI led me to [WMI Troubleshooting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/wmisdk/wmi-troubleshooting) which lists the error code as `0x80041003 WBEM_E_ACCESS_DENIED` - *"The user does not have permission to perform the operation in WMI."* Remember to run the script in an elevated process or you won't have the needed permissions to access the WMI classes.

Answer (score 0):

Years later, but in case you see this or anyone else stumbles across it:

```
Dim objShell, intBitLockerProtection
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
intBitLockerProtection = objShell.NameSpace("C:").Self.ExtendedProperty("System.Volume.BitLockerProtection")

Select Case intBitLockerProtection
    Case 0
        WScript.Echo "Unencryptable"
    Case 1
        WScript.Echo "BitLocker enabled"
    Case 2
        WScript.Echo "BitLocker disabled"
    Case 3
        WScript.Echo "BitLocker encrypting"
    Case 4
        WScript.Echo "BitLocker decrypting"
    Case 5
        WScript.Echo "BitLocker suspended"
    Case 6
        WScript.Echo "BitLocker enabled and locked"
    Case 8
        WScript.Echo "BitLocker waiting for activation"
    Case Else
        WScript.Echo "Unknown"
End Select
```

This works even WITHOUT elevation / admin credentials.  (Note that the original script in the question works if run as admin.)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).